# Why the reducer hook would trigger twice when I put it into the context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create an undo-redo component, which is working properly in [DEF.js](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-66i5zh?file=src%2Fundo_redo%2FDEF.js) component.
The URL for `DEF.js` is [here](https://react-66i5zh.stackblitz.io/def). I click 'go' button to change all the content of the grid, I can click "back" to roll back the content cell by cell.

When I import it into the [Redo.js](https://react-66i5zh.stackblitz.io/redo), it is dispatched twice when it is triggered.
The URL for `Redo.js` is [here](https://react-66i5zh.stackblitz.io/redo).

The only difference is that I put the undo-redo component in the context in Redo.js.

In Redo.js, when I copy 2 cell content and then paste it to the new location,
after that I press `Ctrl-Z` it rolls back the content twice, you may see the word "undo" show twice in the console. (The attached image shows the situation)

I have tried to put the different variable in the keyDown callBack hook dependency array, it does not help.

```
let keyDown=useCallback((e)=>{
    console.log("keyDown");
    if (e.ctrlKey){
        //console.log(e.which);
        switch (e.which){
            case 89:
                //console.log("redo:"+JSON.stringify(rosterList));
                console.log("RedoBody.redo="+rosterList.canRedo);
                if (rosterList.canRedo){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    rosterList.redo();
                    props.updateContextValue({type:"updateShiftValue"});
                }
                break;
            case 90:
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("RedoBody.undo="+rosterList.canUndo);
                if (rosterList.canUndo){
                    rosterList.undo();
                    props.updateContextValue({type:"updateShiftValue"});
                }
                break;
            default:break;    
        }
    } else {
        switch (e.which){
            case 27://handle "Esc" key event
                selectedRegionUtil.clearCopiedRegion();
                break;
            case 37://handle left arrow key event
                selectedRegionUtil.selectNextCell(e,-1,0);
                break;
            case 38://handle up arrow key event
                selectedRegionUtil.selectNextCell(e,0,-1);
                break;
            case 39://handle right arrow key event
                selectedRegionUtil.selectNextCell(e,1,0);
                break;          
            case 40://handle down arrow key event
                selectedRegionUtil.selectNextCell(e,0,1);
                break;    
            default:break;                 
        }
        props.updateContextValue({type:'updateSelectedRegion',value:selectedRegionUtil});
    }    
},[props,rosterList,selectedRegionUtil]);
```

What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Can't you create a [*minimal* reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Ok, I need some time to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I convert the custom hook `useUndoUtil` into a normal javascript object `UndoableData`, it works.